# Oracle indexes. "DISTINCT_KEYS" vs "NUM_ROWS". Do I need an NONUNIQUE index?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a table in which I have a lot of indexes. I noticed that in on one of them "DISTINCT_KEYS" is almost the same as "NUM_ROWS". Is such an index needed?

Or maybe it is better to remove it because:

1. takes a place on the database.
2. When adding data to a table, it does not necessarily slow down the refreshing of indexes.

What do you think? Will deleting this index slow down the queries using the name of this column?

[image: Indexes]

Comment: Is that a unique index maybe?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name this is NONUNIQUE

Comment: An index is created for a purpose, not because the distinct_values is close or far from num_rows. Unique indexes have distinct_keys=num_rows. So, you better find out why the index is there before removing it.

Answer (score 4):

> > Is such an index needed?

All you can tell from statistics like `DISTINCT_KEYS` and `NUM_ROWS` (and other statistics like histograms) is whether an index *might* be useful.  An index is only truly "needed" if it is actually being used by queries in your system.  (See `ALTER INDEX ... MONITORING USAGE` command)

An index having `DISTINCT_KEYS` that is almost equal to `NUM_ROWS` certainly might be useful.  In fact, it would be much more natural to suspect an index to be useless if `DISTINCT_KEYS` was a very low percentage of `NUM_ROWS`.

Suppose you have a query:

```
SELECT column_x
FROM   table_y
WHERE  column_z = :some_value
```

Suppose the index on `column_z` shows `DISTINCT_KEYS` = 999999 and `NUM_ROWS` = 1000000.

That means, on average, each distinct key has (very) slightly more than one row.  That makes the index very *selective* and very useful.  When our query runs, we will use the index to pull out only one row of the table very quickly.

Suppose, instead, the index on `column_z` shows `DISTINCT_KEYS` = 2 and `NUM_ROWS` = 1000000.  Now, each distinct key has an average of 500,000 rows.  This index is worthless because we have to read each half of the blocks from the index and then still probably wind up reading at last half of the blocks from the table (probably way more than half).  Worse, these reads are all single block reads.  It would be way, way faster for Oracle to ignore the index and do a full table scan -- fewer blocks in total to read and all the reads are multi-block reads (e.g., 8 at a time).

For completeness, I'll point out that an index with `DISTINCT_KEYS` = 2 and `NUM_ROWS` = 1000000 *could* still be useful if the data is very skewed.  That is, for example, if one distinct key had 999,000 rows and the other distinct key had only 1,000 rows.  The index would be useful for finding the rows of that other (smaller) distinct key.  Oracle gathers histograms as part of its statistics to keep track of which columns have skewed data and, if so, how many rows there are for each distinct key.  (Over-simplification).

#### TL;DR It's very likely a good index and no more likely to be "unneeded" than any other index in your system.